# Moving files from google drive to terminal server using SFTP

Tags: sftp, file-transfer

I want to get a folder that has subfolders on to a terminal server using SFTP. The source folder is in Google drive. Can somebody provide me how to write a script using linux commands?

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be SFTP then the only thing I've found is using this

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/filemage-public/filemage-gateway-linux

Google drive does not present SFTP by default.

If you are ok with regular FTP then using this
https://www.upf.edu/web/sct-sit/google-drive-ftp-adapter-beta-tutorial
Will allow you to use standard FTP commands to download from Google Drive